# piontcloud to depth image codification

Tags: ros, depth-image, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a depth image in a cv::Mat(height,widht,CV_64F) where each pixel is either 0 if it has no 3D or the distance to produce a 3D point allong the optical ray through that pixel. This distance is encoded between a minimum and maximum distance in the range [0..255]. I know how to convert cv::Mat to sensor_msgs/Image using cv_bridge. However I have not found how to properly codify the information in my cv::Mat image so I can visualize its 3D in rviz. Could you tell me how to convert it? I have been reading and the only information I found was [this](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html) but I it has not been helpful to me.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236223/piontcloud-to-depth-image-codification/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should convert your depth image from scaled values to meters (as 32-bit float), as described in [REP- 0118](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html), and publish this as a sensor_msgs/Float .

Then run the `depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz` node from [depth_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc), and remap its `image_rect` topic to the topic where you are publishing your depth image. This will publish sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 messages on the `points` topic.

You can then view these messages with the PointCloud2 display type in rviz. (make sure your fixed frame in rviz matches the frame_id)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0